# query: {} return at whereHas in postman but data there is in table. Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, connect, wherehas

in CitizenService there is  service_id but this query returning query: {} in postman. in model connected service();

```
$query = CitizenService::whereHas('service', function (Builder $query)  {
        $query->where('service.id', 1);
    });
    return response()->json(['query' => $query]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `id` instead of `service.id` inside the where() clause.

Can you try this:

```
$query = CitizenService::whereHas('service', function (Builder $query)  {
    $query->where('id', 1);
});
return response()->json(['query' => $query]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually execute the query. You have built a query, but have not ran it.

```
$result = $query->get();
```

Or with your code:

```
$query = CitizenService::whereHas('service', function ($query)  {
    $query->where('service.id', 1);
})->get();

return response()->json(['query' => $query]);
```

You don't need to type-hint the argument to the Closure, but if you do make sure it is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Comment: then you have to figure out what that error is ... you have not executed your query, you were just returning a query builder not a result

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are returning a query builder

Look at this

```
$query = CitizenService::whereHas('service', function ($query)  {
    $query->where('id', 1);
})->get();

return response()->json(['query' => $query]);
```

Make sure you defined the proper relationship

For more information [querying on relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)